# Returning data from a function wrapped event

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, promise

```
function form_submit(){
  $('form[action="/specific"]').on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this)
    var data = $this.serialize()
    return $.ajax({
      "method": "get",
      "url": "https://endpoint.com",
      "data": {
        "data": data
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I would like to be able to capture the promise from `$.ajax` from outside the function. Something like `form_submit().then()` doesn't work because it's all wrapped up in the `.on` event. How would someone be able to return something specific like this from an event?

Is the solution to trigger a custom event with the `request` as a parameter?

```
function form_submit(){
  return $('form[action="/specific"]').on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this)
    var data = $this.serialize()
    var request = $.ajax({
      "method": "get",
      "url": "https://endpoint.com",
      "data": {
        "data": data
      }
    })
    $this.trigger("submitted", [request]);
  })
}

form_submit().on("submitted", function(e, request){
  request.then(function(response){
    console.log("logging")
    console.log(response)
  });
});
```

Comment: Why did you place `submit` event handler **inside** `form_submit` function?

Comment: @Regent as a rule of thumb I don't like any of my jQuery code to infect the global scope good for exporting variables with module loaders too (es6, commonjs, amd) so most of my jquery selectors are wrapped within functions. My code looks more like this https://gist.github.com/reggi/3898f13c4fb392c96132#file-klaviyo-js, importing and exporting with es6 modules.

Comment: @Regent I could also just return the event callback for submit like this and leave the selector out entirely. The usage is commented out below https://gist.github.com/reggi/3898f13c4fb392c96132#file-klaviyo-alt-js

Comment: Classic DOM events are synchronous, they don't support this. However new APIs add `event.waitUntil(promise)` method.

Comment: Function that just returns function... Don't you think you overcomplicate the code? But you can still use [$.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) even in your strange code.

Comment: Some like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff7j99sz/), but function in `.done()` will be called only once. Or you can simply use callback function: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff7j99sz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to capture the promise from $.ajax from outside the function

Then you need something like a reactive Observable and not a promise since a promise represents a one time event and resolves once and you need this to happen multiple times. Promises are awesome for one event things. I'm going to use RxJS here but this would work equally well with libraries like Bacon:

```
var el = $('form[action="/specific"]');
function form_submit(){
   return  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(el, 'submit').flatMap(function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();
       var $this = e.target;
       return $.ajax(...); // flatMap on observable will wait for results like a `then`
   });
}
```

Which would then let you do

```
form_submit().subscribe(function(result){
    console.log(result); // log all results from submits
    // can also .flatMap or .map to chain like a promise `then`
});
```

Note that if a form submit only happens once you can make a promise from the event and then `.then` for it but as I always like to say - promises solve a very specific problem very well - there is no silver bullet for concurrency in general - each problem has the tools that solve it well.